# Rails 3.1 Application does not automatically update div

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails 3.1 application where the  view has the following link:

```
<%= link_to("Answer Question",question_ajaxans_path(@question.id),:remote=>true)%>
```

Which has the controller option:

```
def answer
    @answer = Answer.new(:question_id=>params[:question_id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

Which renders this partial code:

```
 alert("it worked");
 $("div#answers").append(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>"answers/form") %>);
```

Firebug shows the partial is rendered, and I have double checked my view to verify that a div with an id of answers was there.

This turorial , http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast, seems to show that it should just load and so do other ones I find on the web.  But, I don't think that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post http://rails3stuff.posterous.com/#!/59899595 I realized that my problem resides in .append().  I didn't wrap the interior in quotes.